# How can i add a user in Azure ad from mvc code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

i am working on web app where i  need to create user into my Azure AD through  programming .i am using Graph API for the same .i have a admin account  register with the Azure AD which is a global administrator, when i am getting token from this user and getting  user details from 
https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6 API , it works fine but when  i  am using same token to crate  user with https://graph.windows.net/ApplicationId/users?api-version=1.6 API , it gives me error

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code for getting token :**

```
  using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                var RequestParameter = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                RequestParameter.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.windows.net"));
                RequestParameter.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
                RequestParameter.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "Client_Id"));
                RequestParameter.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", Email));
                RequestParameter.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "******"));
                var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://login.windows.net/App_ID/oauth2/token") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(RequestParameter) };
                response = await client.SendAsync(Request);

            }
            var a = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Can any 1 suggest Something ?
    Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48385996/2698119

Comment: Have you added the necessary write permissions on Azure AD Graph API and granted them?

Comment: @juunas yes that was exactly the problem. i added permission but it take time to reflect i guess.i execute the same code today and its working now. Thanks

Comment: Ahh yeah sometimes caching can be an issue.